# TFL Unified API, empty body for all line disruption responses

Tags: rest

Trying to query for current disruptions on an underground line and receiving `[]` as the body for every response.

**The request I'm trying to send:**

> https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/bakerloo/Disruption?app_id=&app_key=

**A request for the line ID works as expected**

> https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/bakerloo?app_id=&app_key=

I get a proper (and expected) response from when making this request.

**So my question is:** If anyone else is using this API and if they have also had similar problems/know how to get something more useful than `[]` as a response.

I've just being using a REST Client (Postman), so it's not coding/language dependant.

Documentation: https://api.tfl.gov.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted the TFL Technical team, their response:

> Apologies for the delay. Unfortunately this endpoint is currently broken. It has been for some time so I will chase this up with our technical team to see what the hold up is. It it helps, the /mode/tube/disruption endpoint works.